# How would you experimentally determine the damping coefficient of a system?

Tags: experimental-physics, oscillators, resonance, vibrations, dissipation

We have a suspended beam that we need to determine the natural frequency, and more importantly the damping, of. To avoid resonance.

The geometry of the beam is a little too complex to rely on theory to sus it out. So we're thinking of determining this experimentally.

To do this I believe all you would need to do would be to strike the beam, or excite it somehow, and record, maybe with a laser, how it vibrates. But I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

Comment: Well, yes, that might be "all", but with various caveats about the number of different modes of vibration that may have different damping coefficients, and difficulties in separating the various modes (they may not be an easy orthogonal set for a complex structure).

Comment: As far as structures go it isn't too bad, it is actually just a pipe with a smaller pipe (sensor) on the inside. However it is swaged at its connection point at the top. But I'm hoping it is simple enough to do this kind of experimentation on.

Comment: As a half-width of the resonance curve?

Comment: Even a pipe will have different excitations, e.g. the pendulum mode, but also some rotational modes along its axis, etc. Might be a problem or not... so my question to your question is: why not simply try it out? Instead of a laser you could use any method to record the position (e.g. a simple camera) and just count the number of oscillations...